# Spills and uneven data distribution during data insertion in spark

Tags: apache-spark, hive, apache-spark-sql

I'm writing my dataframe into the hive table. Overall, task succeeds and everythings seems fine. When I look in UI, insertion task looks like this

[image: insertion Task]

Before insertion the data was evenly distributed and there were no spills(ticks).

[image: All Stages]

The way I insert the data

```
df
.coalesce(100)
.write
.mode(saveMode) // overwrite
.insertInto(tableName)
```

Update: Added SparkSubmit

```sh
spark-submit \
--class ${MAIN_CLASS} \
--master yarn \
--deploy-mode client \
--executor-cores 2 \
--driver-memory 6G \
--executor-memory 4G \
--conf spark.app.name=${STAGE} \
--queue ${QUEUE_NAME} \
${TARGET_JAR} \
```

Here's my query

```scala
def getDF = spark.table("myTableName")
    .filter('time_key >= DATE1 && 'time_key <= DATE2)
    .groupBy('c1, 'c2, 'c3)
    .agg(count('*) as 'c4)
    .select('c1,
      concat_ws("#", 'c2, 'c3) as 'c5,
      row_number() over
        Window.partitionBy('c1).orderBy('c4.desc) as 'rn)
    .groupBy('c1)
    .agg(collect_list(when('rn <= 10, 'c5)),
      collect_list('c5))
```

Comment: 1) can you print spark-submit here ?  2) what is the logic you arrived at coalesce(100) is it just random ? if its random before coalesce how many partitions are present ? coalesce will do minimal shuffle... it wont avoid shuflle completely.

Comment: We usually use coalesce to reduce the number of output files. Number 100 gives me files that weight around 60mb in the hdfs.

Comment: @РамазанСаатов Can you also post AppContext.scala + RowCountMetric code inorder to relate them with the shuffle metrics image.

Comment: @QuickSilver I added the query I'm running